# When javarx2 Flowable subscribesOn Schedulers.computation what happens if tasks exceed thread pool size

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, rx-java2

when javarx2 Flowable subscribes on Schedulers.computation what happens if tasks exceed thread pool size?

I read that Scheduler, default thread count is the number of available CPUs.
But who if at all takes care of unscheduled tasks?

How do I read about its behavior?

```
    Flowable
            .fromArray(accountsMap.keySet().toArray())
            .flatMap(key ->

                Flowable
                    .just(key)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                    .doOnNext(sameKey -> {

                        //do my stuff

                    })
            )
            .blockingSubscribe(a ->
                {
                    logger.info("blockingSubscribe received: " + a);
                }
            );
```

An important part of the answer is where do I read up on this information? 
as I found it hard to attain from 
[official class description](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html)

Answer (score 0):

The default schedulers don't place a limit on the number of tasks scheduled as they use the `Executors.newScheduledThreadPoolExecutor()` call to create workers. Having more work than cores is not an issue.

However, if you use a custom `Executor` wrapped in a scheduler and they reject work, the error is propagated to the global error handler. Unfortunately, that's an unrecoverable situation for RxJava as it can't signal an error to the observer due to possible protocol (concurrency) violations. (i.e., in general, the error signal should be also scheduled, which may not be possible because that could be rejected as well, plus the other side may still be executing concurrently.)

Comment: We delegate to the behavior of [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) which are implemented usually via [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) derivatives.